# How do I ssh without a password if im already using github for a key?

Tags: git, ssh

I'm not entirely certain how keys work.

I have finally set up github to store 2 SSH keys, one for my local machine and one for my server.

I have read a few guides on how to make it so when i ssh into my server i dont have to store a password, but im not sure how to do this where i dont overwrite the keys for github?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your server, append your local machines [public] key to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

Since you've got keys from both server and local machine on github, I assume you know how to generate the keys and where to find them.

Comment: You can also use `ssh-copy-id` instead of manually editing `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.